# How to get the two next siblings of selection with -soup-contains in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors, wikipedia

**Intention**
I am working on extracting data about all countries from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazil). I want my parser to be generic enough to work for all countries.

Let's say I am extracting now GDP (PPP) from all countries. In [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazil), they are placed inside an infoBox table. The problem is that GDP(PPP) is split among 3 different rows in the table.

**This is the structure:**

```
   <th scope="row" class="infobox-label">
                              <a href="/wiki/Gross_domestic_product" title="Gross domestic product">GDP</a>&#160;
                              <style data-mw-deduplicate="TemplateStyles:r886047488">.mw-parser-output .nobold{font-weight:normal}</style>
                              <span class="nobold">(<a href="/wiki/Purchasing_power_parity" title="Purchasing power parity">PPP</a>)</span>
                           </th>
                           <td class="infobox-data">2020&#160;estimate</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="mergedrow">
                           <th scope="row" class="infobox-label">
                              <div class="ib-country-fake-li">•&#160;Total</div>
                           </th>
                           <td class="infobox-data"><img alt="Increase" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Increase2.svg/11px-Increase2.svg.png" decoding="async" title="Increase" width="11" height="11" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Increase2.svg/17px-Increase2.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Increase2.svg/22px-Increase2.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="300" data-file-height="300" /> $1.391 trillion<sup id="cite_ref-IMFWEOEG_10-0" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-IMFWEOEG-10">&#91;10&#93;</a></sup>&#32;(<a href="/wiki/List_of_countries_by_GDP_(PPP)" title="List of countries by GDP (PPP)">20th</a>)</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr class="mergedbottomrow">
                           <th scope="row" class="infobox-label">
                              <div class="ib-country-fake-li">•&#160;Per capita</div>
                           </th>
                           <td class="infobox-data"><img alt="Increase" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Increase2.svg/11px-Increase2.svg.png" decoding="async" title="Increase" width="11" height="11" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Increase2.svg/17px-Increase2.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b0/Increase2.svg/22px-Increase2.svg.png 2x" data-file-width="300" data-file-height="300" /> $14,023<sup id="cite_ref-IMFWEOEG_10-1" class="reference"><a href="#cite_note-IMFWEOEG-10">&#91;10&#93;</a></sup>&#32;(<a href="/wiki/List_of_countries_by_GDP_(PPP)_per_capita" title="List of countries by GDP (PPP) per capita">92nd</a>)</td>
                        </tr>
```

**Here is what I tried so far:**

```
site= "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brazil"
country = requests.get(site)
countryPage = BeautifulSoup(country.content, "html.parser")
infoBox = countryPage.find("table", class_="infobox ib-country vcard")
#find GDP PPP
tds = infoBox.select('th:-soup-contains("PPP") + tr')
print(tds)
```

**The problem**
That code prints the row of the GDP PPP itself and not the one after it despite using the '+ tr' as a CSS selector.

Can anyone tell me what I did wrong?
How to select the table row after the one I find using CSS selector?

Answer (score 1):

i don't think you can achieve what you want with css selectors. one way or another you'll have to store the rows or get the indices of the rows. if you transform the `select` result into a generator you can use `next`

```
trs = (tr for tr in soup.select('tr'))
for tr in trs:
    if 'PPP' in tr.text:
        print(next(trs).text)
        print(next(trs).text)
>>> • Total $3.328 trillion[8] (8th)
>>> • Per capita $15,642[8] (84th)
```

Comment: this is really helpful. How do you suggest generalizing this to extract all the features of the country in the infobox? would I have to write it one by one or is there a smarter way?

Comment: the smart way is to use wikidata, but it's hard (there's a stackexchange specialized in these questions: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/). scraping infoboxes is random, but easier (if you already know the data you want to retrieve use a dict). it's your call

Comment: Great, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`beautifulsoup4 4.9.3` - To select the next sibling `<tr>` you can go with:

```
soup.select_one('tr:has(th:-soup-contains("PPP"))~tr')
```

Or you want both of them:

```
soup.select('tr:has(th:-soup-contains("PPP"))~tr')[:2]
```

To get the texts:

```
[x.text for x in soup.select('tr:has(th:-soup-contains("PPP"))~tr')[:2]]
```

Comment: this returned an error.

Comment: NotImplementedError: Only the following pseudo-classes are implemented: nth-of-type.

Comment: are your libraries up to date - maybe you should update them.